# How to perform unit testing on Postgres using SQLAlchemy in Windows?

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, flask-sqlalchemy, database-testing

I am working on a Flask app for APIs and created few Flask-SQLAlchemy models.
I have written a function which takes a list of dictionaries and insert them into Postgres database model tables as rows using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

It's inserting the data into main Postgres database when I hit the API which calls the insertion function. Now I'm writing test cases for the insertion functionality. But I don't want to insert the data into my main Postgres database.

Instead I want to insert the data into temporary a dummy Postgres DB and also create the tables with the models that I have and insert rows into those tables.

I have gone through [testing postgres db python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815872/testing-postgres-db-python) and [Python Unit Test : How to unit test the module which contains database operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159952/python-unit-test-how-to-unit-test-the-module-which-contains-database-operation) also. It didn't help much. Is there any other way to do unittesting on dummy Postgres DB using Python, Flask-SQLAlchemy?